# Write on contenteditable div? imacros

Tags: javascript, html, css, imacros

I'm building a imacros scrip but can't seem to write on a contenteditable div.

This is the scrip that imacros makes up when I click to make a comment.

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>a<SP>comment...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:Pf&&TXT:
```

While I'm typing there's nothing happening in the scrip unless I click on the comment again then it writes this.

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:"whatever I typed"
```

But when I run it, it says

```
RuntimeError: element DIV specified by TXT:"whatever i typed" was not found, line 6 (Error code: -921)
```

The html for the comment:

```
<div id="z13uu53isp2oj3z1n23tspvykmzcgztxv04.editor" jsname="L9AdLc" class="cp"><div class="Pf"><div dir="LTR" role="textbox" g_editable="true" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable" id=":39.f" contenteditable="true"><br></div></div></div>

<div class="Pf"><div dir="LTR" role="textbox" g_editable="true" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable" id=":39.f" contenteditable="true"><br></div></div>
```

Is there any way around this? or a different program that'll be able to do this.

Comment: Use EVENT command and record what you type.

Answer (score 0):

You should try "POS=1" instead of "POS=2", it seems that there's only one tag with the text specified, and you trying to find the second one:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:"whatever I typed"
```